# cell phone as modem via bluetooth - livecd

Tags: linux, bluetooth, livecd

I'd like to connect to internet on my laptop by using my cell phone as modem. This cellphone has Bluetooth and I own usb bluetooth dongle. Are any livecds (livedvds or whatever) that are already preconfigured that I could use for this?

Comment: Why do you insist on using a LiveCD? Also, why won't you state what distro you currently use or who your cell phone carrier is?

Comment: Because I thought that maybe it'll be easier and preconfigured. My phone is Sagem my421Z.

Comment: @CarlF - I believe lorem wants a Live{CD|DVD} because its preconfigured and likely works out of the box. He might also want to preserve his existing OS (and not install the distro). His choice of media is not really relevant, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu 10.10 you dont need any thing ,
For Ubuntu 10.04 or other linux distros you need to install   [blueman](http://blueman-project.org/)

type:
 `sudo apt-get install blueman`
in you terminal

if however you only wish to use it on a live cd get ubuntu 10.10 live cd

Comment: I don't use ubuntu. Does this work on some sort of ubuntu based livecd? Any idea? Or install just won't go through if it's not on hd?

Comment: Ubuntu installation cd also acts as a live cd , it allows you to try it out before you install it , download 10.10 and make a bootable cd/usb

Answer (score 0):

I try some distros, and found 
1. Trisquel Live DVD i18n 6.0.1
2. Mint LMDE Cinnamon U8

this are have pre-installed bt, and my bt-doungle work only under gnome-shell-3.xx, blueman doesnt.